# Functions not defined but can be used in console (Webpack)

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When using webpack I'm having issues with functions

Functions defined like this aren't available at all:

```
function foo() {
    console.log("bar")
}
```

When I define a function like this it works in the console:

```
window.foo = function() {
    console.log("bar")
}
```

But it doesn't work when called from code like

```
window.test = function () {
    foo()
};
```

`<button onclick="test()">`

Comment: Hi whats the ask here?

Comment: Looks like a scope problem. If you can only get window.foo to work, you must be calling the function outside of its scope.

Comment: What do you mean by "aren't available at all". That's a completely correct way to make a function.

Comment: @AlainCruz they probably mean "not available at time of invocation"

Comment: I can't call them from the console or script. To be clear, I'm using webpack and didn't have this issue until I converted to webpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Webpack creates a separate scope for each module.
The proper way to declare variables/functions/etc on the global context is by using the `window` object.

Keep in mind that you don't need the global context (window) in order to share functions between your modules.
You can expose functions from a module by using the [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) statement, and use them on other modules in your project.

Comment: When I use the window object, functions work in the console but not when called from other parts of code, even though they are defined before use

Comment: I am guessing that the module, on which you are trying to call the function, is loaded before the module in which that function is declared (and added to the global context). You need to verify that the module that declares the function is loaded before the module using it.

I recommend you to use the import and export statements, instead of the global context.

Comment: It's at the top of the js file so I don't see why it wouldn't be, unless webpack messes with execution order?

Comment: do you define and call the function in the same file?

Comment: In that case your test function should have foo in its scope.
If I will see the full code perhaps I will be able to see what the problem is.